# Mapping request body fields in logic apps

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

We have configured common alert schema for alerts and we are using a  ticketing software and whenever we receive alert it should create a ticket.

In the logic app I have to make Post API call for creation of ticket with following json object, some fields are hard coded values:

```
{
    "subject": "",
    "Id": "123456789", // Hard code value
    "priority": "",
    "email": "test@test.com",   // Hard code value
    "status": "Open" // Hard code value
}
```

Parse Json sample payload schema for Alert:

```
{
    "data": {
        "alertContext": {
           
            },
            
        },
        "customProperties": null,
        "essentials": {
            "alertContextVersion": "123",
            "alertId": "123",
            "alertRule": "Test Alerts",
             "description": "test",
            "severity": "Sev4"        
        }
    },
    "schemaId": "test"
}
```

I have to map "subject and "priority" fields with alert json object "description" and "severity":

```
subject-->description
priority --> severity // sev0 =high ,sev1=medium, sev2 =low
```

How can I achieve this using logic app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `Parse JSON` You can directly map its objects in the compose connector with the required fields. Below is my logic app flow.

[image]

You can use the below Code view to reproduce the same in your Logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": {
                    "customProperties": null,
                    "data": {
                        "alertContext": {}
                    },
                    "essentials": {
                        "alertContextVersion": "123",
                        "alertId": "123",
                        "alertRule": "Test Alerts",
                        "description": "test",
                        "severity": "Sev4"
                    },
                    "schemaId": "test"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": {
                    "Id": "123456789",
                    "email": "test@test.com",
                    "priority": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['essentials']?['severity']}",
                    "status": "Open",
                    "subject": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['essentials']?['description']}"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "customProperties": {},
                            "data": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "alertContext": {
                                        "properties": {},
                                        "type": "object"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "essentials": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "alertContextVersion": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "alertId": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "alertRule": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "description": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "severity": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "schemaId": {
                                "type": "string"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```